# javascript timer reset at certain interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I want to restart my count up timer every 5 seconds from the following example: http://jsfiddle.net/stursby/wYUzq/5/

So far, it starts and stops fine, even resets. I would just like to have it automatically go back to 0 and start counting up again after, say, 5 seconds.

I've tried using setInterval() but got weird timing resets from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could add this check in your `display()` function

```
if (ms / 5000 > 1)
{
    swreset();
    startstop();
}
```

Comment: wow, that's it. Just couldn't figure it out... been staring at the same code for too long.

Comment: @stursby happens to all of us. :P  Glad I could help. :)

Comment: What is with the `(ms / 5000 > 1)`? Is there something wrong with `(ms > 5000)`?

Comment: @david yes there is. :)  Only when the value reaches 5000 will the division be greater than 1.  Until then it will be a fraction.  You could use that if you changed it to be `if((ms / 5000)>>>0)` or `if(Math.round(ms / 5000))`, but at that point `if(ms / 5000 > 1)` seems simpler to me.

Comment: @JosephMarikle What have you been smoking?

Comment: @david oh! I thought (as my comment indicates) you were saying `(ms / 5000)`, which almost makes sense.  My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

I would use modulos to update the display accordingly. Replace:

```
    $('#count span').text(ms);
```

with:

```
    $('#count span').text(ms%5000);
```

at every occurrence.